# Mapping NERDTREE commands to arrow keys in VIM

Tags: vim

I have the following setup in my .vimrc to help me navigate between open tabs in NERDTree

```
map  <C-l> :tabn<CR>
map  <C-h> :tabp<CR>
map  <C-n> :tabnew<CR>
```

However this doesn't seem to be working.. Anyone any clues

This is what my entire .vimrc looks like:

[image: These are the first 59 lines]

After this is when my mapping commands appear

Comment: 1. Tab pages have *nothing* to do with NERDTree. 2. Please post your `~/.vimrc` because there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your mappings (except, maybe, the use of `:map` but well…). 3. You didn't explain *how they fail*.

Comment: I am not able to copy-paste from VIM into windows.. so I have attached a screenshot

Comment: When you say arrow keys do you me up (`<UP>`), down (`<DOWN>`), left (`<LEFT>`) and right (`<RIGHT>`)? You currently have control h, control l and control n mapped in the lines you posted.

Comment: yes .. I mean <UP>, down, left and right arrow keys. I want to use them along with the Ctrl keys to shift between tabs. Any clue how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

Finally figured out. The below worked for me

nnoremap tp: tabprev
nnoremap tn :tabnext
nnoremap tf :tabfirst
nnoremap tl :tablast

Now i can use tp, tn to move between previous and next tabs